# show OS specific popup in react native app

Tags: react-native

in my react-native application, i'm just finding out the way to open the system specific popup rather then react-native Modal or Alert.
is there any way to show device OS specific popup?
i.e. when we are using some USSD in phone dial pad and popup appears.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```js
import {
      ToastAndroid,
      Platform,
      AlertIOS,
    } from 'react-native';

function notifyMessage(msg) {
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    ToastAndroid.show(msg, 2000)
  } else {
    AlertIOS.alert(msg);
  }
}
```